# Problem in Oracle 19c installation on Windows 10

Tags: oracle, installation, windows-10

I am trying to Run setup.exe as part of Oracle 19c installation on windows 10.

I have downloaded the zip file and extracted it in a folder inside C drive.

**When I try to run setup.exe by right click and run as administrator option, a command prompt just flashes for a split of a second and nothings starts after that.**

Answer (score 10):

I have found the solution:

1. After extraction, rename the extracted directory to db_home
2. Move the db_home directory to the root of your Hard Drive ( **in my case its C:\db_home** )
3. run setup.exe as an administrator.

You will see a cmd window pop up and then the red window with the Oracle symbol in it.

Do NOT skip step 2nd step as that is how I was finally able to get it to install.
This also worked with 19c.

Comment: Unfortunately, the 18c and 19c Installation Guide for Wiindows is about as poorly written and confusing piece of oracle docs I've ever seen, and I've been at this sincd 1995.  After making sure you've met hardware and sofware reqs, it boils down to this: Create your ORACLE_HOME with the os 'mkdir' command.  2) Unzip the distribution into the created ORACLE_HOME.  3) run setup.exe from the unzipped directory in ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: God, hate oracle... Thanks for your tip, step 2 saved me

Comment: In my case, I just needed to remove space from the directory name. No need to move the directory, or run as administrator.

Comment: @TrojanName you are a life saver.  Spent hours on this.  All it was.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This has been so helpful.  I spent a whole day trying to figure this out in order to connect to an Oracle DB with Power BI.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the problem. After seeing this thread, in a while, I figured it out. Apparently, keeping the db_home folder inside a folder that has space in its name caused me the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and read something about problems with extremely long paths in packages and using the native Windows unzip utility. I unzipped the package using 7-zip instead and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install from d partition and does not work. Then I just move all the installation folder to c partition and it works fine.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an Oracle DBA and I don't know when the change happened or what the source of issue is, but when installing the Oracle client you can no longer have a space " " in the path for the Oracle setup.exe file.

It doesn't matter what utility extracted the files or what drive or path is used (except there is and always has been an issue with very long path names) - it just cannot have a space in the path.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has a simple solution:

1. When we run the Setup file we see a flash CMD in the background...
2. Your System Environment variable path(DB home) has Space in it.
3. It should be no space(db_home)

This personally works for me to install.